# Setting up Perforce with AWS - "Rollback Complete" on stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, perforce

Alright, I am following this tutorial to [set up Perforce HelixCore with AWS](https://www.perforce.com/products/helix-core/install-enhanced-studio-pack-aws#outputs). I've followed all of part 1 "Define your AWS environment" verbatim, however my parent stack's status went from `CREATE_COMPLETE` to `ROLLBACK_COMPLETE` which means something has failed.

No status reason is given though this is the log where the rollback starts -

> was not successfully created: The following resource(s) failed to
> create: [PerforceServerInstance].

I am not versed in AWS. What may have occurred here?

Comment: The server instance wasn't created successfully. Look further down the stack messages to see if it gives you some useful info. If it doesn't work out the AMI it uses and try a manual deploy to see if you get more useful messages.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim, said, you can try to figure it out by digging through the other sub-stacks that it tried to create. Unfortunately, during teardown, some of those get removed so you may not have the messages anymore.
The most common reason for this is that AWS failed to create one of the resources, usually because your account is new and they are trying to avoid fraud or because they are short on that type of resource.
The Virtual Windows Workstation is the main culprit for this. I would recommend trying again but setting the Windows Workstation to False so it won't be created. You can also try choosing different instance types that are more plentiful, like the t3 instances. You can always upgrade or downgrade the instance types later.